# Change Whatsapp-for-Mac notification sound

Tags: macos, notifications, whatsapp.app

I'm here to ask you if is possible to change Whatsapp for Mac Notification sound. I tried to find any not-sound in library folder and into Whatsapp's Package contents without no result. Could you help me solving this trouble? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible with the current desktop version of WhatsApp.

Some users have tried changing the notification sound on their iPhones in the hope it would also change it on their 'synced' desktop version, but this doesn't work either.

And, as you've stated, showing package contents doesn't seem to reveal any audio files.

However, the desktop version has only been around for about six months, so it's ripe for user feedback. I'd send an email to [support@whatsapp.com](http://support@whatsapp.com).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to change the ringtone on WhatsApp, however you need to do some fiddling with the app contents. The ringtone is located at `/Applications/WhatsApp/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Resources/Opening.m4r`.

Grab whatever mp3 you can find, convert it to m4r, rename `Opening.m4r` to `Opening_bak.m4r`, then move your ringtone to the Resources folder (of course, before doing this, rename it to `Opening.m4r`).
Then it should work.